# How is this circuit for level converting (5V<>3.3V) working?

Tags: mosfet, level-shifting, ttl, 3.3v

Does anybody know, how is this circuit exactly working? It is level converter between 5V and 3.3V logic and it is bi-directional.

I have some theory, but I am not sure with it (I never worked with MOSFET before). And what is that diode for?

[image]

I take this image from SparkFun's [datasheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/Level-Converter-v10.pdf) ([level converter](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8745)).

Comment: Sorry for this question. It was easy to google the answer. I found this document —  [Level shifting techniques in I2C-bus design](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/interface/pdf/an10441.pdf) (PDF) which describes this circuit in section 2.1.1, page 4. And it seems, I cannot answer my own question, because I have small reputation.

Comment: Check if you can answer your question now. You probably are able. I am trying to find that restriction in the list.

Comment: It say "users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking". So I'll answer this question later.

Comment: Okay, A time delay I can understand for users that do not know the system yet. Please take the time to answer it when you can!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When no device is pulling down the line, the "left side" (with lower voltage) is in high state by pull-up resistor. The voltage between the *gate* and the *source* is below the threshold voltage and MOSFET isn't conducting. So the "right side" (with higher voltage) is pulled up by pull-up resistor too.

When the "left side" pulls down the line to a low state, the voltage between the *source* and the *gate* rises above the threshold and MOSFET starts to conduct. So the "right side" is then pulled down to a low state via the conducting MOSFET.

When the "right side" pulls down the line, the diode between the *drain* and the *gate* connects the "left site" to low state, causing the MOSFET to conduct, so both sides are pulled low to the same voltage level.

More detailed description is in [Level shifting techniques in I2C-bus design](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/interface/pdf/an10441.pdf) (PDF) in section 2.1.1, page 4.

*If I made some mistakes, feel free to correct me.*

Comment: Can you summarize it here?

Comment: Done. I edited my answer.